# Python: Code crashes - Restart Script

Tags: python, gmail

```
imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
mail.login(user,passw)
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

while True:
    try:
        result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')
        uid_list = data[0].split()
        print len(uid_list), 'Unseen emails.'
        time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Quitting'
        return 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail_new2.py", line 12, in <module>
    mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 642, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1060, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 890, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: SELECT => socket error: EOF
```

The code connects to gmail and returns unread emails. it works fine but sometimes it returns that error and crashes.

How can I correct the error or restart the code when it crashes?

Comment: This must be inside a function somewhere; else, `return` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement that is failing is `mail.select` you can wrap it in a `try/except` block and implement a retry policy.

If the problem is related to service availability, you may want to try a [exponential backoff strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) with a timer that grows exponentially to schedule the retry attemps.

One simple example would be as follows:

```
selected = False
retry_timer = 1
while not selected:
    try:
        mail.select('inbox')
        selected = True
    except imaplib.abort:
        time.sleep(retry_timer)
        retry_timer *= 2
```

Comment: what should I add in the except?

Comment: Incidentally, a cute decorator for exponential back off can be found here http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry